# How to generate menu with sub items?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to generate a menu, in wordpress, with sub items. My current attempts have been something like this,

```
$mainmenu       = wp_create_nav_menu( 'main' );
$submenu = array('menu-item-type' => 'custom',
                'menu-item-url' => '/',
                'menu-item-title' => 'sub-menu' );

wp_update_nav_menu_item( $mainmenu, 0, $submenu );

var_dump(wp_get_nav_menus());
```

The `var_dump()` shows the mainmenu but has a count of 0 where I expected 1 sub item.
What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Wordpress does not create the relationship for you and thus there will be no record in the table wp_term_relationships that links the post with post_type "nav_menu_item" (sub menu) to the mainmenu.

Using the method "wp_set_object_terms" I create the relationship myself.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

```
$mainmenu       = wp_create_nav_menu( 'menu' );
$submenu        = array('menu-item-type' => 'custom',
                'menu-item-url' => '/',
                'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
                'menu-item-title' => 'sub-menu' );

$subID          = wp_update_nav_menu_item( $mainmenu, 0, $submenu );
wp_set_object_terms($subID, 'menu', 'nav_menu', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Menu and sub menu.Adjust styling as per your desire

```
<?php
$args = array(
'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
'menu' => 'Main menu',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'container_class' => 'menu-header'
);

$args = array('lang' => $langfornt);
$linkfilter = new ModifyLinkFilter($args); 
wp_nav_menu("menu='Main menu'");
$linkfilter->unregister();


?>
```